# Creating the same scale for graphs with different scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, cowplot

I have a data set where I created `ggplots` for each `ind` where I end up with four different graphs. I had put these graphs into a list, and then used `plot_grid` from `cowplot` to get a single output that displays all four graphs at once. I'm not quite sure how to create a generic example here.The four graphs have different scales, but I would like my end product to have the same scales for each graph from the `plot_grid` output. How would I do this?

Here is a sample data set:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
rsq <- lapply(1:length(unique(iris$Species)), function(i) {
  cor(iris[iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i], "Sepal.Length"], iris[iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i], "Petal.Length"])^2
})

p.list <- lapply(1:length(unique(iris$Species)), function(i) {
  ggplot(iris[iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i], ], aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
    geom_point() + theme_bw()+
    geom_text(aes(x=min(Sepal.Length),y=max(Petal.Length),label=paste0("R= ",round(rsq[[i]],2))))
})

cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = p.list[1:3], nrow = 1, ncol = 3, 
                   labels = "AUTO")
```

Comment: To help us to help you could you make your question reproducible by sharing the code you tried and the desired output? Also, why not simply facet by `ind` which will automatically give you the same scale.

Comment: I have edited the post using the `iris` data set as an example. I don't use facet on the data because the graphs are constructed from multiple different data sets, and I essentially paste them all together using `plot_grid` which doesn't plot them with the same x and y scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two options to achieve your desired result.

1. If you want to stick with `plot.grid` you could achieve your desired result by setting the same limits for the x and the y scale in each of your plots. To this end compute the overall minimum and maximum in your data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

rsq <- lapply(1:length(unique(iris$Species)), function(i) {
  cor(iris[iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i], "Sepal.Length"], iris[iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i], "Petal.Length"])^2
})

d_list <- split(iris, iris$Species)

xmin <- min(unlist(lapply(d_list, function(x) min(x["Sepal.Length"]))))
xmax <- max(unlist(lapply(d_list, function(x) max(x["Sepal.Length"]))))
ymin <- min(unlist(lapply(d_list, function(x) min(x["Petal.Length"]))))
ymax <- max(unlist(lapply(d_list, function(x) max(x["Petal.Length"]))))

p.list <- lapply(1:length(unique(iris$Species)), function(i) {
  ggplot(iris[iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i], ], aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(xmin, xmax)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(ymin, ymax)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_text(aes(x = min(Sepal.Length), y = max(Petal.Length), label = paste0("R= ", round(rsq[[i]], 2))))
})

cowplot::plot_grid(
  plotlist = p.list[1:3], nrow = 1, ncol = 3,
  labels = "AUTO"
)
```

[image]

2. As a second approach you could make use of faceting as I mentioned in my comment. To this end bind your datasets into one and add an id variable. Additionally put the r-square values in a data frame too. Doing so allows you to make your plot using facetting:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d_list <- split(iris, iris$Species)

rsq_list <- lapply(d_list, function(x) {
  data.frame(
    rsq = cor(x["Sepal.Length"], x["Petal.Length"])[1, 1]^2,
    Sepal.Length = min(x["Sepal.Length"]),
    Petal.Length = max(x["Petal.Length"])
  )
})

d_bind <- dplyr::bind_rows(d_list)
rsq_bind <- dplyr::bind_rows(rsq_list, .id = "Species")

ggplot(d_bind, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_text(data = rsq_bind, aes(label = paste0("R= ", round(rsq, 2)))) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to select a few levels at a time in `facet_wrap`? In my data set, I have 3000+ levels for the `ID`. This would no doubt break the code if I ran it on my computer.

Comment: Hi John. Okay. I See. You data is actually more demanding as the datasets I have to deal with. Maybe `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate` is helpful, as it allows to split a facetted plot over multiple pages.